# Transition to Modal View Controller with Keyboard Visible

Tags: objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller

Is it possible to present my modal view controller with the keyboard already visible? Currently, the modal's text view becomes the first responder as soon as it's view is loaded, which causes the keyboard to animate coming up from the bottom.

[image: This is halfway through the transition (they keyboard is animating as well)]

I'd like the keyboard to already be on the modal and be a part of it's transition. Any suggestions?

Comment: sooner than `viewDidLoad` or `init` ... No

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyboard is a separate `UIWindow` object.  It is not in the same view hierarchy as your view controller's view.  To make this happen, you would have to dig around in the `UIApplication`'s `windows` property for the keyboard window and replace its default animation with a custom animation.

Comment: +1 for `The keyboard is a separate UIWindow object.` However, suggesting that someone `dig around in the UIApplication's windows property for the keyboard window` is probably not a great idea - unless you don't care about the app store - or about your application working when an iOS update is released.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the `becomeFirstResponder` code in `vieWillAppear`, but that isn't the "right" thing to do anyway.

You will probably need to replace the actual keyboard animation with a custom animation to force it to load immediately and without scrolling up.